# Does cmake set INTERNAL apply FORCE?

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

From the CMake `set()` command's [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html#set):

> If  is INTERNAL, the cache variable is marked as internal, and will not be shown to the user in tools like cmake-gui. This is intended for values that should be persisted in the cache, but which users should not normally change. **INTERNAL implies FORCE.**

By "*INTERNAL implies FORCE*", does this mean that `FORCE` is applied, or does this read that any use of `INTERNAL` should also apply `FORCE`?

Said another way- are the following equivalent?

```
set(foo "value" CACHE INTERNAL "description" FORCE)
set(foo "value" CACHE INTERNAL "description")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does cmake set INTERNAL apply FORCE?

Yes in most cases.

`FORCE` isn't currently applied implicitly with `INTERNAL` during the *initial configuration* of a generated buildsystem if the cache variable is specified via commandline with no type (granted- this is a strange edge-case- one has to ask why a user would think to set something that's supposed be internal via commandline at all).

From just trying it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(hello)

# uncomment for first test
# set(foo OFF CACHE BOOL "set to OFF")
# set(bar OFF CACHE BOOL "set to OFF")

set(foo ON CACHE INTERNAL "set to OFF on commandline")
set(bar ON CACHE INTERNAL "set to OFF on commandline" FORCE)

message("foo: $CACHE{foo}")
message("bar: $CACHE{bar}")
```

If you set the cache entries prior via `set()`:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build --fresh
<...>
foo: ON
bar: ON
<...>
```

If you set the cache entries prior via commandline with types specified:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build --fresh -Dfoo:BOOL=OFF -Dbar:BOOL=OFF
<...>
foo: ON
bar: ON
<...>
```

If you set the cache entries prior via commandline with types unspecified:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build --fresh -Dfoo=OFF -Dbar=OFF
<...>
foo: OFF
bar: ON
<...>
```

If I'm reading correctly, this little kink has been mentioned on the Kitware issue tracker for CMake: [set: CACHE INTERNAL type initialization drops value (#22734)](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22734). See Brad King (one of the Maintainers)'s reply [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22734#note_1044880):

> The problem is in the code [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/v3.21.3/Source/cmMakefile.cxx#L1937-1941) that is used to initialize the type of a cache entry that was defined without one.  It accounts for `FORCE` meaning that the old value won't be preserved, but not for type `INTERNAL` meaning "force" implicitly.
> This patch fixes it:
>
> ```
> diff --git a/Source/cmMakefile.cxx b/Source/cmMakefile.cxx
> index 23b97ed789..db7d048e01 100644
> --- a/Source/cmMakefile.cxx
> +++ b/Source/cmMakefile.cxx
> @@ -1911,7 +1911,7 @@ void cmMakefile::AddCacheDefinition(const std::string& name, const char* value,
>         cmStateEnums::UNINITIALIZED)) {
>      // if this is not a force, then use the value from the cache
>      // if it is a force, then use the value being passed in
> -    if (!force) {
> +    if (!force && type != cmStateEnums::INTERNAL) {
>        value = existingValue->c_str();
>      }
>      if (type == cmStateEnums::PATH || type == cmStateEnums::FILEPATH) {
> ```
>
> Further investigation is needed to determine other possible effects of that change and whether it needs a [policy](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-policies.7.html).
> This probably hasn't been noticed often because the `INTERNAL` type is not typically meant to be set publicly.  As a workaround, one can pass the type explicitly on the command line: `-Dvar:INTERNAL=value`.  That skips the problematic code path.

Answer (score 0):

> Does cmake set INTERNAL apply FORCE?

Yes.

> By INTERNAL implies FORCE does this mean that FORCE is applied,

Yes.

> Are the following equivalent?

Yes.

Comment: almost ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​ ​